# What work is wasFound doing in this version of contains?

Tags: javascript, callback, underscore.js, contains, reduce

In the following code, I'm not sure how the parameter wasFound is doing its work:

```
_.contains = function(collection, target) {
  return _.reduce(collection, function(wasFound, item) {
    if (wasFound) {
      return true;
    }
    return item === target;
  }, false);
};
```

I  would expect `wasFound` to be initialized at `undefined` (although I've seen in comments that its initialized at `false`; how does that happen). I also can't see how `wasFound` itself gets updated.

I've seen a lot of discussion on SO that discusses this version of contains, but nothing that parses this particular piece. Help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"wasfound" is the accumulator value of the reduce. In your code, it is initialized with "false" since this is the third argument to the "_.reduce" method, indicating that the "target" element has not been found before the loop starts. Then, the "reduce" iterates over the collection and assigns the current element to "item". On every iteration step, it checks if "wasFound" is true, which would indicate that we already found the element in a previous iteration step and return "true" to pass that information to the next iteration. Else, we compare the current collection item to the "target" item. If they are of the same type and value, we return "true" to indicate that to the next iteration, else "false". This has the effect, that after having iterated over the whole collection, we know if the target element is contained, since one of the iteration steps will have set "wasFound" to true and this is what is returned. If it is not contained, the value stays false.

In general, the reduce accumulator (here "wasFound") is set to the return value of the previous iteration step. And since the first step has no previous one, the third argument to "._reduce" is used as initializer.